# using .val not working with variables?

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery, mmy code is supposed to have 2 inputs (btn1 and btn2) in html that when modified, reflect a change on the other input, this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('input','.btn1',function(){
        var value3 = 1;
        $(".btn2").val(value3);

    });
    $(document).on('input','.btn2',function(){
        $(".btn1").val(6);
    });
});
```

When modifying the first input, nothing changes, but when changing the 2nd one, it does show the value "6". What Am I doing wrong that doesn't show up my variable?

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1 class="titu hidden" >Quantity 1</h1>
    <input class="btn1 hidden" type="number" name="cantpag" value="<?php echo $cp; ?>">

    <h1 class="titu hidden">Quantity 2</h1>
    <input class="btn2 hidden" type="number" name="cantreinv" value="<?php echo $cr; ?>">

    <input class="sbmtbtn hidden" type="submit">
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('input', '.btn1', function() {
    var value3 = 1;
    $(".btn2").val(value3);

  });
  $(document).on('input', '.btn2', function() {
    $(".btn1").val(6);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h1 class="titu hidden">Quantity 1</h1>
  <input class="btn1 hidden" type="number" name="cantpag" value="0">

  <h1 class="titu hidden">Quantity 2</h1>
  <input class="btn2 hidden" type="number" name="cantreinv" value="0">

  <input class="sbmtbtn hidden" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: when you call `.val()`, what output does it give you?

Comment: Nothing, the original value is 0 and doesnt shange, but when writing in the 2nd input it does show the 6 at the 1st input

Comment: I've added a runnable code snippet to your question and it works just fine

Comment: I'm with Phil on this one, code seems to change values as expected.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors?